# Using RHEL/AL2, `curl` works when I use the `--cacert` param, but fails without

Tags: linux, curl

**Using RHEL/AL2, `curl` works when I use the `--cacert` param, but fails without**

When I try to connect to a server I get an error `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`.

However when I provide the cert itself from `/etc/ssl/certs` via `--cacert` the problem goes away.

I'm not too familiar with certificates but I'd imagine how `curl` pulls the cert for a specific server is somehow not right.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which cert do you provide from `/etc/ssl/certs`?

Comment: an internal cert for my company

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use Self-Signed Certificates and to let OS tools validate chain

- Place the certificate under `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`
- Update the trust via `/bin/update-ca-trust extract`
- Additionally, if Java is installed on the system, place a symlink to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts`

**Further Readings**

- [Using shared system certificates](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/securing_networks/using-shared-system-certificates_securing-networks)
- [How to configure your CA trust list in Linux](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/configure-ca-trust-list)
- [How to update cURL CA bundle on Red Hat?](https://serverfault.com/questions/394815/)